# Correct method to normalize two data sets

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, statistics, discrete-mathematics, standard-deviation

I have to normalize two data sets w.r.t y-axis values while x -axis values are common in both.
I have used in `gnulpot` three different methods, can any one tell which one is correct? since on web there are multiple ways given.
Data set #1 (data3.dat)

```
0.3 2391
0.4 2203
0.5 2819
0.6 2795
0.7 2664    
0.8 3139    
0.9 3652
```

Data set #2 (data4.dat)

```
0.3 0.00107
0.4 0.00113
0.5 0.00196
0.6 0.00169 
0.7 0.00255 
0.8 0.00292
0.9 0.00363
```

Method 1: divide y axis values with largest y value in respective data set and plot

```
stats "data3.dat" using 1:2 name "A"
stats "data4.dat" using 1:2 name "B"

plot "data3.dat" using 1:($2/A_max_y) w lp,"data4.dat" using 1:($2/B_max_y) w lp
```

The output looks like this

[image]

Method2: Divide second data set with largest y value of both data set and plot

```
stats "data3.dat" using 1:2 name "A"
stats "data4.dat" using 1:2 name "B"

plot "data3.dat" using 1:2 w lp,"data4.dat" using 1:($2/A_max_y*B_max_y) w lp
```

The output looks like this

[image]

Comment: Which is "correct" depends what you are trying to achieve. If you want to compare the shapes of the two distributions then method 1 is correct. If you want to compare the relative magnitudes of values in the two distributions then method 2 is correct. What is the data and what conclusion are you trying to draw?

Comment: Thanks @sammygerbil , first Data set represent number of conflicts in network for x parameter values, second data set contains service time required for respective x parameter value. Since x values are same so i want to normalize w.r.t y values and want to see from graph what x value should i choose, being optimum.  The low number of conflicts and low service time are desirable. How can i get optimum value of x from graph, does it require data sets graph to intersect? what if they dont ?

Comment: You need a statistic which tells you how close to *optimum* you are. For example you could multiply no. of conflicts $n$ and service times $t$, and choose the minimum product $nt$. But this function is arbitrary. If you think no. of conflicts is more important you might use $n^2 t$ instead. You don't need to normalise either $n$ or $t$ or $nt$. Just plot $nt$ against $x$ and look for the minimum.

Comment: Thanks @sammygerbil